# Why does AdjustWindowRect not set the right client size?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a Win32 program with a 256x240 window and a menu inside. When I use AdjustWindowRect to set the correct client area size, the client area is too small. Here is the code for setting the size:

```
UINT WINDOW_WIDTH = 256;
UINT WINDOW_HEIGHT = 240;

DWORD window_styles = WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU;

SetProcessDPIAware();

RECT rect;
rect.left = 0;
rect.top = 0;
rect.right = WINDOW_WIDTH + rect.left;
rect.bottom = WINDOW_HEIGHT + rect.top;

AdjustWindowRect(&rect, window_styles, true);

HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx
(0, CLASS_NAME, WINDOW_CAPTION, window_styles,
CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

Comment: I have edited the code to declare rect before it is used as well as set the DPI awareness. However it still does not work.

Comment: What client size does that give you?

Comment: The client is 240x201 instead of 256x240.

Comment: What happens if you add `WS_CAPTION` to the styles?

Comment: Adding WS_CAPTION fixed the issue. Thanks.